# Django template onclick inline html javascript alternative

Tags: javascript, python, html, django, django-templates

I read that using `onclick` is deprecated and bad practice.

I have this `do_something` function that will proccess the data inside of `onclick`. How I can convert this to javascript:

```
{% for user in all_user %}
<tr>
    <td>{{ user.code }}</td>
    <td>
        <button type="button" onclick="do_something('{{ user.name }}', '{{ user.age }}', 1, '{{ user.desc }}');">small</h6></button>
    </td>
</tr>
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Set a **class selector** on the buttons so you can apply the event listener to it via Javascript.
2. Your function requires parameters that are unique per user, so you'll need to set those parameters as **data attributes** on each button.

```html
{% for user in all_user %}
  <tr>
      <td>
          <button class="user-action-btn" type="button"  
          data-name="{{ user.name }}" 
          data-age="{{ user.age }}" 
          data-desc="{{ user.desc }}">small</button>
      </td>
  </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

3. In Javascript, get the elements by class name and set the event handler for each.

Here's an example of the code in Javascript

```js
(function() {
        var classname = document.getElementsByClassName("user-action-btn");

        var myFunction = function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var name = this.getAttribute("data-name");
            var age = this.getAttribute("data-age");
            var desc = this.getAttribute("data-desc");
            do_something(name, age, 1, desc)
        };

        for (var i = 0; i < classname.length; i++) {
            classname[i].addEventListener('click', myFunction, false);
        }
})();
```

And here's the JQuery equivalent

```html
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $('.user-action-btn').on('click', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var name = $(this).data('name');
        var age = $(this).data('age');
        var desc = $(this).data('desc');
        do_something(name, age, 1, desc);
});
```

Comment: Thanks, I did not know this data- on html. Great help.